# how to remove '['']' from string and write in txt just the text

Tags: python, string, hash, format

my code in java is writing in a txt what is in the print, but I would like it to save the "tag" without the characters '[' ']', which end up coming along with the tag, can anyone help me?
'''

```
 sleep(1)
        #tags = r.tags
        ip_address = droplet_response.json()['droplet']['networks']['v4'][0]['ip_address']
        tags = droplet_response.json()['tags']
        tag = tags.split([''])
        print('Nome:',r.name, 'ID:',r.id, 'IP:',ip_address, 'TAG:',tags)
```

'''

print>> Nome: aaatYnqSi.karzono.com ID: 305480378 IP: 192.241.141.16 tag:  ['aaatYnqSi']

Comment: Are you saying you want to convert `['aaatYnqSi']` to `'aaatYnqSi'` ?

Comment: exact, I want you to save only: aaatYnqSi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, it looks like `tags` is a string - but your comment says it is a `list`. You can extract the first item (in this case, only item) from the list with unpacking

```py
tags = ['aaatYnqSi']
clean_tag, *_ = tags
clean_tag = clean_tag.strip()
print(clean_tag, end='')
# 'aaatYnqSi'
```

Comment: returned me the following error: ERROR - 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: That way it worked, thanks <3

Comment: I would like to also remove the "\n" at the end, could you help me with that too?

Comment: Take a look at the `.strip()` method in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

Comment: I tried strip() but it didn't work: ERROR - 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: `strip()` is a string method, it works with strings - you can apply it to `clean_tag` like, for example, `clean_tag = clean_tag.strip()`

Comment: keeps breaking line and I don't know why, I did exactly as you told me

Answer (score 0):

You could unpacks the *tags* list as follows:-

```
print('Nome:',r.name, 'ID:',r.id, 'IP:',ip_address, 'TAG:',*tags)
```

However, this may not give the desired results if there are two or more elements in the list

Comment: it returned the following error: ERROR - 'tags'

Comment: @JanilsonJunior If you replace your print code (from your question) with this answer you will **not** get an error

Comment: I would like to also remove the "\n" at the end, could you help me with that too?

Comment: @JanilsonJunior Use str.rstrip()

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I would apply it in the code?